# Why isn't my selector function being called in my custom Swift class

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have a custom class called Utilities which has a method called `createCustomeTextField`for creating a custom text field. The custom textfield has a target added to it for all events but its not calling the objective c selector function when I type in the text field.

Here is my custom class:

```
class Utilities {
    
    static func createCustomInputContainerView(withImage image: UIImage, andTextField textField: UITextField) -> UIView {
        
        let view = UIView()
        let iv = UIImageView()
        view.setHeight(to: 50)
        iv.image = image
        view.addSubview(iv)
        iv.anchor(left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, paddingBottom: 8.0, width: 24.0, height: 24.0)
        
        view.addSubview(textField)
        textField.anchor(left: iv.rightAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingLeft: 8.0, paddingBottom: 8.0)
        
        let dividerView = UIView()
        dividerView.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(dividerView)
        dividerView.anchor(left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, height: 0.75)
        return view
    }
    
    func createCustomTextField(withPlaceholder placeholder: String) -> UITextField {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.textColor = .white
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
        tf.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
        tf.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleEditingDidBegin(sender:)), for: .allEvents)
        return tf
    }
    
    @objc func handleEditingDidBegin(sender: Any) {
        print("DEBUG: Got here")
    }
}
```

Here is where my instance of Utilities is created. Its in a view controller class.

```
...
    private lazy var emailContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = Utilities.createCustomInputContainerView(withImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_mail_outline_white_2x-1"), andTextField: emailTextField)
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var passwordContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = Utilities.createCustomInputContainerView(withImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_lock_outline_white_2x"), andTextField: passwordTextField)
        return view
    }()
    
    private let emailTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = Utilities().createCustomTextField(withPlaceholder: "Email")
        return tf
    }()

    private let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = Utilities().createCustomTextField(withPlaceholder: "Password")
        tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return tf
    }()
...
```

Comment: Where is called `createCustomTextField(withPlaceholder:)`? Could your `Utilities` instance released too soon?

Comment: `self` refers to an instance of `Utilities`. Where is it?

Comment: Added code showing where Utilities is created

Comment: PS: `Utilities()` creates indeed an instance but it is thrown away at the end of the closure. You need a strong reference.

Comment: @vadian What's the solution then?

Comment: As I said you need a strong reference, assigned to a property or as singleton.

Comment: @vadian aren't all vars and lets strong by default?

Comment: Not necessarily. `createCustomTextField` returns the created text field which doesn't have a strong reference to the `Utilities` class, so the  `Utilities` instance is deallocated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228806/discussion-between-stephen501-and-vadian).

Answer (score 0):

Made Utilities a singleton class and set the tag property of the text fields.